# How can I open or export a abcddb file in Windows 7 Excel?

Tags: file-conversion

I have a file in the abcddb format. This file was saved on a Mac. I am trying to open in Windows 7 in either Excel or Access. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The file is actually an SQLite 3 datafile.

The closest match would be Access, but it will not open the file as such. You will have to install an ODBC connector, set up a connection and open each table. Not trivial, I am afraid, but doable.

Check http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/ for an SQLite ODBC connector. **Note:** some antivirus show a heuristics alert for the executable, it is probably safe.

**Command line:**
If you have access to the sqlite3 command line tool (comes standard in OS X), you can list the tables (there are 24) with

```
echo .tables | sqlite3 file.abcddb
```

and you can export each table to CSV with

```
sqlite3 -csv -header file.abcddb "SELECT * FROM TABLE;" > TABLE.csv
```

and open it with Excel or Access.

Of course, you can "play" with SQL SELECTs. A CSV list of Name, Surname, Phone (with a line for each phone number, hence possibly more than a line for each person) can be got with:

```
sqlite3 -csv -header file.abcddb "SELECT ZABCDRECORD.ZFIRSTNAME AS 'First Name', ZABCDRECORD.ZLASTNAME AS 'Last Name', ZABCDPHONENUMBER.ZFULLNUMBER AS 'Phone' FROM ZABCDRECORD INNER JOIN ZABCDPHONENUMBER ON ZABCDPHONENUMBER.ZOWNER = ZABCDRECORD.Z_PK;" > telephones.csv
```

ZABCDRECORD is the "main" table with a row for each contact. But data that cn be multiple for each contact (phone numbers as above, email addresses, physical address, URLs...) is in separate tables, each containing a ZOWNER column that "points" to column Z_PK (autonumeric) in ZABCDRECORD (technically, they have it as a foreign key).

**Alternative GUI software:** you may download [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) for OS X or Windows (PortableApps package available too for the later). Just open the file then use File->Export->Table(s) as CSV file.

Comment: That file has virus. Is it safe or not?

Comment: [Virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/es/file/1753f49a2747a3044f1538441367c0bf987add02c061d880431ab367f64b284c/analysis/1458658796/) shows two _heuristics_ detections (antivirus sees strange code but does not recognize a known virus) for the SQLite ODBC connector. It is most probably safe as the other 54 antivirus do not detect anything, but to be in the safe side it is probably better to use another tool. I am going to add [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) above.